# Is there a way in node or shell-scripting to know if a child process starts its own subprocess?

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, ipc

Say I have a simple 1-line shell script `test.sh` that starts up some other process, like `npm start` or `python server.py`.

Now say I run that shell script from within a parent node program, i.e.:

```
let child = process.spawn("./test.sh");
```

Is there any way for the node process to keep track of the processes started by that shell script? Say I want to get the `pid` of the python or npm process and monitor its life cycle.

It's equally useful to know if there's a way for a shell script to do it, because I could write a shell script to run the other shell script, and then have my node project run my shell script as a man-in-the-middle....so if either the shell or node can do it, either way works.

Is it possible?

Comment: See also: [communication between multiple processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132102/communication-between-multiple-processes)

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the children of a process using something like this in python and providing the PID of the parent as the first argument

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import psutil

for child in psutil.Process(int(sys.argv[1])).children(recursive=True):
    print(child.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can [`strace`](https://strace.io/) the target process and look for `fork` system calls.

Similar techniques are probably possible on most other platforms, though the details will differ. On some platforms, you need `root` or equivalent privileges to inspect the internals of a process, even if it belongs to yourself.